# Querying ArrayList return Index of Arraylist

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which is not doing what I am expecting.

```
Private Function getIndexOfArrayList(arrlist As Array) As Integer
    For index As Integer = 0 To arrlist.Length - 1 Step 1
        If (arrlist(index).Equals(If((mscbpisdepaap.Text.ToString = mscbpisdepaap.SelectedItem.ToString), mscbpisdepaap.SelectedItem.ToString, String.Empty))) Then
            Return index

        End If

    Next
    Return -1

End Function
```

The function should compare a set of arraylist with the equal property. And if this is true, it should return the index. If not, it should return -1

But this function is not doing what I am expecting, it always returns -1.

Did I make some mistakes with the ternary operator here?

If I am not doing that with the ternary operator, I got my correct index.

The function should give me the correct index, if there is no index, it should retrieve -1.

Can someone proofread that function please?

Comment: There's already an `IndexOf()` function, and `ArrayList` means **something else** in VB.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass `arrList` as `Array` use `String()`

`arrList` is an unfortunate choice for your variable name. There is such a thing as an `ArrayList` although it is obsolete. Also the name of your Function is misleading; you are dealing with an array not `ArrayList`.

Remove the extra set of parenthesis in the outer If.
Don't call `.ToString` on a `Text` property, it is already a `String`.
There is another extra set of parenthesis around your inner If condition.

```
Private A() As String = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i = getIndexOfArray(A)
    Debug.Print(i.ToString)
End Sub

Private Function getIndexOfArray(arrlist As String()) As Integer
    For index As Integer = 0 To arrlist.Length - 1 Step 1
        If arrlist(index).Equals(If(ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, String.Empty)) Then
            Return index
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(A)
End Sub
```

Doesn't the `SelectedItem` always equal the `Text` property?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function getIndexOf(items() As String) As Integer
    Dim value = If( mscbpisdepaap.Text = mscbpisdepaap.SelectedItem.ToString(), mscbpisdepaap.Text, "")
    Return items.IndexOf(value)
End Function
```